# use of AltGr key

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout

I’m using Emacs with a Bépo keyboard (which is specialized for the French langage and code). I’ve never had the problem before (either with Linux or Windows) but now on my last install (with WSL: Windows Subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu) the following problem occurs:

Characters like ">" and "{" are only reachable with the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, for instance "}" is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and so <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>}</kbd> which I use to go down one paragraph is now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+[<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>]: the problem is emacs doesn’t seem to understand it, it simply considers <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and so I find myself whithin the prompt buffer. On the other hand <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> alone works well as it writes "}" whithin the current buffer.

Actually, for all combinations <kbd>Alt</kbd>+[<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd>] emacs understands <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>.

As a complement, when I use `screenkey` to check what’s really been typped, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> shows `ISO_Level3_Shift }`: does this mean the problem comes from the OS and not emacs?

Thanks.